# Sending data between sites

Tags: php, forms, redirect, hyperlink

What is a good method to send data from site A to site B without passing a new URL parameter?

For instance, on site A I submit `apples are red` via a form. How can I send that data to site B without modifying site B's URL structure?

example `http://siteb.com/?data=apples+are+red`

Not sure if trackbacks or pingbacks use a similar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're just trying to submit the form directly to siteb, simply use method="get" and action="http://siteb.com"

lets say you are sending an offset where siteb will use it to determine a page number from an arcticles listing, your form on sitea would be something like:

```
<form method="get" action="http://siteb.com">
  <input type="text" name="offset" id="offset" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Comment: The "offset" value 0 from site A can be retrieved in site B without passing a URL parameter?

Comment: if you submit the form like that it will point you to 
http://siteb.com?offset=0
if you don't want the parameter to show on the querystring use method="post"

Comment: this doesn't say how you will know what parameters to send.  From his question he's asking how to know what to send without changing siteb's url structure.

Answer (score 1):

The query string, like your example above, but siteb needs to know what data its getting.

Think of it like the affiliate programs, where you pass a linke to siteb (in this case the affiliate site) from your sitea via the query string, it works because site b knows what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like:

```
$data = 'http://siteb.com?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$ch = curl_init($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Hmm I haven't had the opportunity to work with CURL yet. I assumed that I would use REST of json. Do you think CURL is best for this type of thing?

Comment: It's not perfect, long load times/timeouts on the other site would hold up your own page load though there are ways to sort of "forget" the process, such as via ajax postbacks to a script doing just this task on your own server since you can't XSS the other domain, which would cause that CURL query to happen after your page load and not affect your own page load times...